# RegExp and String combination crashes Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I have the following RegExp to validate an email address:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

Running it on a basic email works beautifully:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$/.test('dave@the-taylors.org');
```

But running it on a long string crashes Chrome:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$/.test('dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd');
```

I've noticed it kicks in at around 40 characters

What is it about this RegExp which is so intensive?

Comment: interestingly this is fine in Firefox but also crashes IE 9

Comment: On Firefox it completes even with a 'ddddddd...' string of length 4096.

Comment: For the record, I was able to boil it down to `/[a-d]([a-d]+)+A/.test('dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd');`, which also hangs - hope it helps in finding the issue.

Comment: Here's an even smaller one :) `/d(d*)*a/`. The `a` makes it obviously fail on a string with only `d`s in it, so this could be considered a performance bug. Maybe you should file a bug on http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues, as the issue is also apparent on Chrome Canary.

Comment: i've boiled your expmple down even further `/(d+)*A/.test('dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd');` it seems to be related to the double plusses which aren't in the original. however it does have a + and a * which causes the same issue

Comment: I did some timing tests using a web worker (to prevent an actual hang) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NZyBj/1/), and it seems like the time to execute `.test` increments about exponentially compared to the length of the string. Perhaps (a wild guess) it's trying out every combination of `d*` and then `(d*)*` before even considering the `a`.

Comment: It looks like this is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=831) in fact.

Comment: @pimvdb: Not really a bug - given a long enough string, the exorbitant number of permutations for `(d*)*` cause the regex engine to calculate nearly forever before deciding it can't match. This is called catastrophic backtracking. Some engine cut their losses after, say, a million attempts - others keep trying. Each behavious has its downsides and upsides.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Thanks for explaining. It's unfortunate the regexp engine does not try scanning the "easy" parts first (here, the `a` that never matches) before starting with all the permutations. Anyway, they decided not to improve this.

Comment: Thanks pimvdb, tim-pietzcker this makes total sense. It's interesting also that the removal of the A at the end returns a result immediately. @tim-pietzcker, if you can add a response as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, let's see what's happening here. You have thankfully already simplified the problem down to what happens when you apply the regex

```
(d+)*@
```

to the string

```
ddddd
```

which clearly can't be matched because the `@` is missing. But what's keeping the regex engine from figuring this out quickly?

Well, `(d+)*` in essence can be fulfilled by the following matches (each group separated by spaces):

```
ddddd
dddd d
ddd dd
dd ddd
d dddd
ddd d d
dd d dd
d d ddd
dd dd d
d dd dd
d ddd d
d d d dd
d d dd d
d dd d d
dd d d d
d d d d d
```

So you have one way of matching the string without breaking up the string, four ways to break it up into two strings, six ways to break it up into three, four to break it into four, and one to break it up into five strings. All these combinations have to be checked by the regex engine before it can declare failure to match when it finally has to face the following `@`.

Why doesn't it figure that out sooner? Well, some regex engines can probably do it with such a simplified example. I bet Larry Wall has that covered. But your actual regex is a bit more complex, so I guess that would be much harder to figure out beforehand. Plus, there is a simple way to ensure all this combination-trying doesn't happen. But I'll come back to that later.

I had been wondering how many such combinations there would be for a longer string than those puny five `d`s:

Let's take a string of length `m` (which can be cut apart in `m-1` different positions). Let's say `n = m-1`. Then you can calculate the number of combinations as follows:

```
1 + (n!/(1! * (n-1)!)) + (n!/(2! * (n-2)!)) + ... + (n!/(n! * (n-n)!))
```

The first and last items are always 1, but the items in-between can get quite large. Let's write a small Python program:

```
>>> from math import factorial as f
>>> def comb(n,x):
...    return f(n) // (f(x) * f(n-x))
...
>>> def ways_to_split(len):
...    return 1 + sum(comb(len-1,x) for x in range(1,len))
...
>>> ways_to_split(5)
16
```

OK, seems to work. Let's try something bigger:

```
>>> ways_to_split(10)
512
>>> ways_to_split(40)
549755813888
>>> ways_to_split(100)
633825300114114700748351602688
```

Hey, there's a pattern here: `ways_to_split(n)` is equal to `2**(n-1)`. See [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98196/22262) for a proof. Anyway. Your regex has `O(2^n)` complexity. Well, now you see why that might take a while...

Thankfully, many regex engines provide protection against this: possessive quantifiers or atomic capturing groups.

```
(d++)*
```

or

```
(?>d+)*
```

both ensure that whatever `d+` has matched will not be relinquished again for trying other combinations. Good news, right?

Well, not if you use JavaScript. It doesn't support either of those features.

Therefore, you either need to rewrite your regex not to be susceptible to backtracking like this:

Instead of

```
(([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)
```

use

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*
```

Or stop trying to use a regex to validate an e-mail address which doesn't work reliably, ever, anyway.

Comment: Seems like you could combine the character classes in the last regex: [a-zA-Z0-9]+[\w\.\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9] - not that it's of any consequence as asker shouldn't be using regex at all.

Comment: @EricWendelin: No. That would make the separators optional again, so you run into the same catastrophic backtracking problems. Also, it would match addresses like `a..-..z` which the original regex would not have allowed. Thanks for your edit, by the way - I posted this answer way after midnight and was getting tired...

Comment: thanks @TimPietzcker, i appreciate the thorough answer. could you clarify what the `!` represents in the equation `(n!/(1! * (n-1)!))`

Comment: @DaveTaylor: It means factorial, i. e. `4! = 4*3*2*1`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is related to your regex not the length of string. I used the following regex for email validation and it didnt crash on Chrome..

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test('dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd');
```

Comment: yeah, i'm curious as to what it is about the regex which is doing the damage. thanks for posting your email regex, that's helpful

Answer (score 2):

Do not validate e-mails with regular expression. I think this was a common knowledge for about twenty years now. It is too complex. An example of mostly complete validation is here http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html and even that doesn't implement the standard completely. It is far more simple to write a function that does the same. When you can validate parts of the email separately it becomes trivial. Besides, as is your case, the function would do this a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is here:

```
[_.-]?
```

If the first `[A-Za-z0-9]+` (you left out the `+`, by the way) runs out of alphanumeric characters to consume, and the next character is not one of the separator characters ( `[_.-]` ), the match attempt should fail immediately.

What happens with your regex is that the first `[A-Za-z0-9]+` starts backing off, giving up the characters it just matched one by one, and letting the second `[A-Za-z0-9]+` (inside the `*` loop) try matching them instead.  That's a lot of combinations it has to try (as Tim's <s>thesis</s> answer explains ☺), and it's all perfectly pointless.

Now have a look at this:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+([_.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+([.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$
```

This regex doesn't enter the `*` loop unless it actually sees one of the separator characters.  The subexpression inside the `*` may be optional, but whatever it *does* match *must* start with `_`, `.`, or `-`.  Similarly, if the regex succeeds in matching the local part and the next character is not `@`, it bails out immediately, where yours goes into another paroxysm of backtracking.

According to RegexBuddy, your regex takes 57 steps to match `dave@the-taylors.org`, where mine does it in 17 steps.  And where yours locks up on the other string, mine reports a failed match in 5 steps.

The moral is: never use a `?` or `*` quantifier on something that isn't really optional.

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm not endorsing the use of this or any other regex to match email addresses.  I'm just explaining what's wrong with the regex in the question.